# C# Async Sockets - Get Data

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

I'm building a simple server, that contains some information and that will be using Async Sockets to get N Connections (I don't really know how many, they can range from 50 to 1000).

The main purpose of this server is to 'verify' the file integrity and version of clients connecting, and if needed send them the updated files so they can patch.

Right now, I'm on the part of getting my sockets running, I can display the data in the console, and everything is fine, problem is, my most important variables are on my 'DownloadServer' class, while my socket functions are on a class named 'ServerSocket'.

My question is, how can I access the data in DownloadServer(that contains an instance of ServerSocket) when said info is requested to my socket. I can't return the data received with Async Callbacks (because they must be void), so what would be the best way to go about this?

Here's my socket code, it only receives a client and prints data sent. What I want to do is acess the received info (likewise, a command for example) and return to the client the request info, for example, if the message received is "GetFileVersion", the server should reply back with the value of the variable it contains (it's a global variable named FILEVERSION), being the problem that I can't seem to find a way to acces that variable.

```
class ServerSocket
 {
    private Socket _socket;
    private byte[] _buffer;
    public ServerSocket()
    {
        _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }

    public void bind(int port)
    {
        _socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
    }

    public void Listen(int backlog)
    {
        _socket.Listen(backlog);
    }

    public void Accept()
    {
        _socket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallBack, null);
    }

    private void AcceptCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        Socket clientSocket = _socket.EndAccept(ar);
        Accept();
        IPEndPoint clientEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint;
        Console.WriteLine("Client Connected: {0}",clientEndPoint.Address.ToString());
        _buffer = new byte[2048];
        clientSocket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceivedCallback, clientSocket);



    }

    private void ReceivedCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket clientSocket = ar.AsyncState as Socket;
            int size = clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);
            byte[] packet = new byte[size];
            Array.Copy(_buffer, packet, packet.Length);
            String data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(packet, 0, packet.Length);



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ;
        }

    }



 }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
What I'd like to do is something like String commandReceived = socket.Receive() (like you would do with synchronous sockets), or some way to acess that command received via that socket.

```
class DownloadServer
{
    private static String UPDATEPATH="";
    private static int FILEVERSION;
    private static string ROOTPATH = "";
    private String SQLUsername = "";
    private String SQLPassword = "";
    private String AccountDB = "";
    private String ServerName = "";
    private SqlConnection sqlConn;

//some logic methods

static void Main(string[] args){
ServerSecurity serverSecurity = new ServerSecurity();
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
        serv.Initialize();
        serverSecurity.Initialize();
        serverSocket.bind(15779);
        serverSocket.Listen(1000);
        serverSocket.Accept();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input the command:");
            var Input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (Input == "Update")
            {
                serv.prepareUpdate();
            }
            else if (Input == "Exit")
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else if (Input == "TestEncryption")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the text to be encrypted:");
                String plainText = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Original Text = {0}", plainText);
                Console.WriteLine("Encrypted Text = {0}", serverSecurity.Encrypt(plainText));
                Console.WriteLine("Decrypted Text = {0}", serverSecurity.Decrypt(serverSecurity.Encrypt(plainText)));
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in your DownloadServer Class :

```
Socket NewSocket;
byte[] buffer = new buffer [1024];
NewSocket = serverSocket.Accept();
```

Then begin Receive from this NewSocket :

```
void Receive()
{
 NewSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, r);
}



 private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Socket CurrentClient = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            int Received;
            try { Received = CurrentClient.Receive(buffer); }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }


            byte[] _buffer = new byte[Received];
            Array.Copy(buffer, _buffer, Received);
            string _Text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(_buffer);

           if(_Text == "GetVersion")
            byte[] infoVersion = Encoding.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(FILEVERSION);
              CurrentClient .Send(infoVersion )
}
```

Comment: So basically, I should code my socket functions inside DownloadServer and not in a separate class? Because that seems to be what you're doing here, which I wanted to avoid, so that my DownloadServer only handled the data and requested ServerSocket to send/receive the data...

Comment: Then why not Put the FILEVERSION in other class named : ServerInfo and makes it Static class so you can access to it from anywhere

Comment: That could Solve it, I'll try it!

Comment: take all your server informations that could be requested by the client to other class and make it static

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a classic design problem where you are attempting to give a class too many responsibilities. In SOLID design, each class should have a single responsibility. The SocketServer would then only be responsible for creating the socket and sending/receiving data. Your DownloadServer would be responsible for creating data to be sent. Another class say ValidationServer, would be responsible for requesting data through the SocketServer and parsing it. A third class, a controller if you will, would be responsible for coordinating calls and passing data between these classes.  In this way your SocketServer and DownloadServer would be decoupled and not require variables from each other.

Comment: That was what I was aiming for here. DownloadServer is the logic part of my program, what I would like to be able to do is just call ServerSocket to send/receive data, then parse it in another class, thing is the async design doesn't seem to let me do it that way. I know I can do that in Synchronous sockets (get bytes from socket, parse them, do whatever i want), but it's a whole new world once I started with Async sockets (i'm pretty new to Async sockets, but I do understand the logic behind it), so would you have any advice? Thank you.

Comment: You have several options here. One method might be to pass a callback into the "Accept" method. When data is received, that callback is called with the data as a parameter. I think however that I would use the TPL to accomplish this task.  The Socket class already has convenient Async methods to do this.

Comment: My idea was that the Async sockets will use threads from the ThreadPool, which means they will always work in the background, allowing the main thread to keep working which is useful in my case (i need to be able to make a new patch, even if people are updating). But I have run into the problem where I can't just call 'ServerSocket.Send('any data i wanna send from download server'), because they run on the background, what I mean is that, I think my socket is not well designed, because I'd like to just call 'ServerSocket.Receive() and ServerSocket.Send("data here")'

Comment: I highly recommend that you look into C# async and await features (and the underlying Socket's SendAsync and other async methods) as it will probably get you what you are looking for in background (non-blocking) functionality.